# No video output on my new Raspberry 4 B

Tags: noobs, pi-4

I just received my new RPI 4. Before I was running RPI 3 B+.

I have: 
  - formatted the same SD with SD Card Formatter for mac
  - download Noobs
  - extracted all files on SD
  - inserted SD on my RPI 4

But nothing happens. I have no video on my TV
My TV is detecting that I have HDMI port connected, but I can't see anything.

What can I do ?

Comment: Are you using the HDMI port closest to the power port? I would download a Buster image and install that instead of Noobs.

Comment: Yes, I am on the port closest to the power port. I tried installing buster directly, I can see 4 raspberries, and a cursor blinking. I also have a red led and a green led. But still no OS

Comment: ah sorry, had to wait a bit. OS appeared. Please put it as an answer